# Order of the boxplots and legend labels with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot

I want to create a boxplot with `ggplot2` and I'd like to organize the plot in the order of the data frame, e.g.

> I know that R organize the boxplot alphabetically. How can I:
>
> 1. Organize the X axis in the order Taste - Color - Capacity
> 2. Switch the boxes, i.e. first the green and then the orange, instead orange and green
> 3. Switch the legend order too, first NaCl and then O_{2}

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)

Chemical <- rep(c("NaCl", "Al2"), times = 3, each = 4)
Quality <- rep(c("Taste", "Color of package", "Capacity"), times = 1, each = 8)
Accepted <- seq(0, 100, by = 100/23)

DF <- data.frame(Chemical, Quality, Accepted)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Quality, y = Accepted, fill = Chemical)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "green"),
                     labels = expression("Al"[2], "NaCl")) +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You have different methods to control the output. A quick solution would be:

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Quality, y = Accepted, fill = Chemical)) +
geom_boxplot() +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "orange"),
                labels = expression("Al"[2], "NaCl")) +
xlab("") +
theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank()) + 
guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Taste", "Color of package", "Capacity"))
```

Simply with the argument `guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))`, manually altering the order of the colors and fixing a specific order on the X axis with `scale_x_discrete` is achieved.

[image]

It is also possible to reorder the levels with `DF$Quality <- factor (DF$Quality, levels = c ("Taste", "Color of package", "Capacity"))` and achieve the same result without use `scale_x_discrete()`.